# react router url issues after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, routes, react-router

I am using React router to change routes. This works well when I develop locally.

My router code looks like this and everything works perfectly.

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" render={(routeProps)=> <Homepage {...routeProps} />}/>
    <Route path="/graph" render={(routeProps)=> <AboutPage {...routeProps} />}/>            
</Router>
```

The issue I am having is when I deploy it to my github page, `http://exampleuser.github.io/react-project`.

As the project is in a react-project folder this `"/"` refers to the actual route which is `http://exampleuser.github.io/`

Can anyone advise how the path should look so it works when deployed?

Comment: Have you tried using `<Switch>` ? `import <Switch> from 'react-router-dom'` and then wrap everything in a `<div>` and then wrap all `<Route>`'s inside `<Switch>`

Comment: I have, but i don't think it is to do with `Switch` - I believe it is to do with the route once I have deployed as it is no longer `"/"`

Comment: put `"/"` `<Route>`in the last not the first?

Comment: are you, by any chance using create react app?

Comment: @randomguy04 I am

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `basename` prop in your router, just make sure you only use that in production and not in development (you could use environment variables for that) your router should look like this:

```
<Router basename="your-react-project">
  {/* routes */}
</Router>
```

If you are using create_react_app, you can just use the env variable `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` like this (which is empty en development so it will work fine for bot dev and production):

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* routes */}
</Router>
```

I actually have a [project running](https://valecarlos.github.io/admin-dashboard) with this configuration and works just fine.

Comment: so it actually works fine when it is the project at the root of my github repo, but it is in a subfolder i.e - `http://exampleuser.github.io/react-project`

Comment: have you tried the first approach? where you can set the basename manually?

Comment: yeah man, just deployed there and it works! the baseman works a treat! Green tick coming up! side question, where do u set the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` variable?

Comment: glad to hear that. You don't have to set it yourself, they briefly explain how it works here https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system

Answer (score 0):

it's an easy fix I came across the same issue here is how I fixed it.

1- go to your root directory in your cPanel or server if you are using apache. and create a .htaccess file

open the file and add the following code to it.

`#jerryUrena is awesome
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]`

after this, your website should work the same way.